# Why won't postbacks work on my domain root?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, postback

I have a form on a masterpage which is very simple but will not work when the site is at the root.

Works fine:

> www.mysite.com/page.aspx
>
> www.mysite.com/another/page.aspx

Does not work:

> www.mysite.com

I click the button and it postsback to

> www.mysite.com/default.aspx

But nothing has executed, now if I try the form again on /default.aspx it will postback and execute fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your form tag code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply, I just figured it out!

I am using isapi to make sure my urls are all lower case, and 301 redirecting any upper case URL's to their equivalant lowercase version.

On postback its action is Default.aspx ... My script was redirecting it to default.aspx and loosing the values before it was posted back.. DOH!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like the default page redirection is either accidentally (or intentionally) losing all form data. I would first suggest not redirecting to a page that doesn't exist.

However, if you insist, I'd try something like [URL rewriting](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx). Hopefully a rewrite from a module will keep the form data intact, but I can't say for sure it will. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an Index.aspx at the root of your site?